# How to change img alt src to div strong using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a group of images inside a div, what I really want to do with javascript is change the src to `<strong>` inside `<div>` and delete the `img alt="image"`

**example:**

I have this

```
<div class="multi-gallery-image show" id="service_preview">
    <img alt="image" src="チャイルドカット¥3000">
    <img alt="image" src="ジュニアカット">
    <img alt="image" src="ハナコカット">
    <img alt="image" src="Hair Styling">
    <img alt="image" src="Manicures">
    <img alt="image" src="Hair Coloring">
</div>
```

and I want to transform each img src to `<div> <strong>` like this

```
<div class="multi-gallery-image show" id="service_preview">
     <div><strong>チャイルドカット¥3000</strong></div>
     <div><strong>ジュニアカット</strong></div>
     <div><strong>トップスタイリストカット</strong></div>
     <div><strong>Hair Styling</strong></div>
     <div><strong>Manicures</strong></div>
     <div><strong>Hair Coloring</strong></div>
</div>
```

at the moment I have this

```
let servicePreview = document.getElementById('service_preview');
console.log(servicePreview);
```

and the result is the same as the second code.

How can I change `img alt src` HTML tags to `div strong` using javascript? or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `<img>` elements from the DOM, then create a `<div>` and `<strong>` for each `<img>` where the inner text of the `<strong>` is the `src` attribute of the `<img>`.

No need for jQuery by the way, the JS DOM API can handle this just fine.

Here's an example:

```js
const target = document.querySelector("#service_preview_divs");
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll("#service_preview img");
imgs.forEach(img => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    const strong = document.createElement("strong");
    strong.innerText = img.getAttribute("src");
    div.appendChild(strong);
    target.appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<div class="multi-gallery-image show" id="service_preview">
    <img alt="image" src="チャイルドカット¥3000">
    <img alt="image" src="ジュニアカット">
    <img alt="image" src="ハナコカット">
    <img alt="image" src="Hair Styling">
    <img alt="image" src="Manicures">
    <img alt="image" src="Hair Coloring">
</div>

<div id="service_preview_divs"></div>
```